# Android - Viewing video stream with ADPCM encoded audio track

Tags: android, audio, codec

I am attempting to interface with a Motorola Blink1 camera (baby monitor) which hosts an unencrypted video+audio stream, the video is mjpeg but of particular interest is the ADPCM encoded audio stream.  The video+audio feed is made available via a public URL on the local network.

Does anyone know how one might connect and decode such a video stream *with the audio* (I know OpenCV etc can do this without audio) within an Android app?  Or failing that, any open source Java lib that can do this?

As an aside the desktop/web interface on the device uses the Java applet based GNU GPL v2 Cambozola viewer here:

http://charliemouse.com/code/cambozola/index.html

which Motorola have modified to add ADPCM support but do not appear to have released the modified source anywhere :-/ however it does indicate that this *can* be done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full credit to Motorola as after I wrote to their tech support requesting their modified GPL source for Cambozola, they did after a couple of months get their dev team to prepare the source code for their web viewer app and publish it here

https://github.com/nikhilvs/cambozola-bms

And it includes the ADPCM decoder routines integrated into it. For future reference they are prepending the JPEG  stream with a short binary stream containing frame count, temperature info and the audio packets.

Kudos to your dev team Motorola for releasing your code in response to a tech support query I really wasn't expecting such a positive response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this right now, and I've identified most of the things needed to decode the ADPCM stream.  Documenting my progress here: http://www.surfrock66.com/improving-the-motorola-blink-baby-monitorcamera/

It's using an open source streamer (GPLv3) which they've modified, code here: https://code.google.com/p/mjpg-streamer/  I'm actually contacting Motorola to get the source now, as they are under obligation to publish their modifications.